# How can I save some chrome://flags to user directory with chromedriver and capybara?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I actually have this .rb file

```
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara-webkit'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome

Capybara.app_host = 'chrome://flags'

describe "Activate", :js => true do
  it "Successfully activated" do
    visit('/')
    find('some flag ID').click
  end
end
```

It correctly activates the chrome flag that I want to, but when I restart the browser, the change disappears.
Is there a way to save the change to user's chrome settings directory?